# Simulating mouse click using python and win32api

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, win32gui

I am trying to simulate a mouse left click on a window (Samsung Flow) but unfortunately it is not working. When I try on a google chrome window it works, but I have tried on Paint and on Samsung Flow but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
import random

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        # if 'Stack Overflow' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
        if 'Samsung Flow' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            print(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
            for _ in range(50):
                l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(random.randint(10, 500), random.randint(10, 500))
                win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
                time.sleep(0.1)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

I know that it detects the window as I am printing the detected text, but I do not know why it only work on the Chrome window.

**Update**

I have tried the following code, to search two windows notepad and browser:

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import time

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        # if 'Notepad' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
        if 'Stack Overflow' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            print(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord("c"), 0)
            time.sleep(0.1)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

And the result was:

- when using on the browser (searching for Stack Overflow window), the window came to foreground and printed the letter c
- when using the notepad the window came to foreground but the letter was not printed! and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.

With the example trying to send the letter C to notepad and the chrome browser I assumed that the first hwnd is the right one BUT in some cases, you have to interact with a child window. A window may have more than one child window, so, I will post a code here where you can find the window to interact with.

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import time

def send_char(hwnd, lparam):
    s = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    print("child_hwnd: %d txt: %s" % (hwnd, s))
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CHAR, ord('c'), 0)
    time.sleep(5)
    return 1

def main():
    main_app = 'Untitled - Notepad'
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, main_app)
    if hwnd:
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, send_char, None)

main()
```

With that you can find the child window that you should send the messages to (the code print the window id and name, send the character and wait 5 seconds, so when you notice the character on your window just get the last printed window id and use it instead of the parent window).

I hope it help someone facing the same problem.